# Echo into multiple files in Batch script

Tags: batch-file, windows-xp, cmd, command-line-interface

How can I echo a line into multiple files in a single command?
Example: `echo Hello World!` into file1.log and file2.log

EDIT: Windows-XP Batch Script

CHALLENGE: Give me a one-liner =D. If it can't be done w/one line I'm not interested.

My solution was

```
ECHO Hello World!>tmp.log & COPY file1.log + tmp.log & COPY file2.log + tmp.log
```

But I'm hoping for one that is a single command and not multiple commands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need it only for single lines (of input) you can write your own tee with batch.

```
@ECHO OFF
rem *** singleLineTee destination1 destination2
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p var=
> %1 echo(!var!
> %2 echo(!var!
```

And use it with `echo hello | singleLineTee file1.log file2.log`

**EDIT:** The same as an one liner

```
echo hello | ( cmd /v:on /c "set /p var=& >> file1.log echo !var!& >> file2.log echo !var!")
```

The `cmd /v:on /c` is necessary to enable the delayed expansion

Comment: Edited post: Need it for Windows-XP

Comment: `tee` is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Obviously, you should put the code above into a batch named `singleLineTee.bat`

Answer (score 3):

```
echo "Hello World" | tee file1.log file2.log
```

Comment: @Mechaflash sorry, I read "batch" as "bash" and thought linux.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something similar to jeb, but keep it in the same batch file as your calling code

```
@ECHO OFF
    del tem1.txt
    del tem2.txt
    call :SingleLineTeeSub "echo Hello" Tem1.txt Tem2.txt
    call :SingleLineTeeSub "echo World" Tem1.txt Tem2.txt
    call :SingleLineTeeSub "Dir tem1.txt" Tem1.txt Tem2.txt
goto :eof

:SingleLineTeeSub
    rem *** call :SingleLineTeeSub "command [params]" destination1 destination2
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    set theCmd=%~1
    >> %2 %theCmd%
    >> %3 %theCmd%
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Will this suit your requirement:

```
(echo hello > file1) && copy file1 file2
```